# Dojo/Dijit - How to allow Vertical Scrolling on a layout control

Tags: dojo, dijit.layout

How can I allow scrolling in this Dojo/Dijit page:

http://www.olexe.com/html/DijitScrollTest.html

I might have 60 or 100 rows to display in the tabControl (id="topTabs").

I think there must be a property such as AllowScrolling but I cannot find it. 
Or do I need to add a child control, and then turn on scrolling in the child control. 
(If you could also point me to the Dijit doc where it is document, that would be appreciated.  I have been hunting for over one hour for it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general scrolling is easily activated by setting the CSS style overflow to "auto". However, I have looked through your page a little and I have a few questions.

First, you add a TabContainer in the center region of the BorderContainer, but then you never add any tabs to that Container that I can see. TabContainers are usually populated with several ContentPanes to acts as different Tabs.

So if you want tabs, then I would add an additional child element in the form of a ContentPane that holds all the content, otherwise I would change the existing TabContainer into a ContentPane.

Either way, it is the ContentPane that should have the overflow: auto;  attribute set to allow scrolling within that element.

Comment: We were vacillating back and forth as to whether we were going to use tabs or not.  So apparently I removed the tabs, and tried just putting the content directly.  I'll check it out tonight. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, Got it more or less working (same page as above updated).  Am I now limited to the two separate scroll bars, or can I set some page-size type parm and just the browser's scroll bar?

Comment: Hmm, if I remember correctly, you have both a header with a fixed height, then a main element with 100% height, that is probably the cause for the browser scrollbar. I think that can be solved by moving the header inside the BorderContainer.

Answer (score 1):

the contents of TabContainer should scroll by default.  Try looking at the declarative example [in the docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/layout/TabContainer.html#dijit-layout-tabcontainer) and use ContentPane children with a title attribute for each.